# Asus k501 Windows 10 keyboard / touchpad problems

Tags: windows-10, keyboard, touchpad

I have Asus k501L with Windows 10 installed on it. 
Laptop just freeze on login screen and that it. (Started few days ago).
Neither keyboard or touchpad are responsible.

However keyboard works in BIOS.
Touchpad works in Windows Repair.

Any ideas how to fix?

I've tried to log in in safe mode - without any success.